# Finding and adding together overlaps in dates from 2 different columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables on my excel workbook. One to track tasks and one to track leave.
I want to see the impact leave would have on each tasks (i.e. the total number of leave days of a resource that would fall within the start and end dates of a task)

[image]

The table on the left contains the tasks. The table on the right contains the leaves.
What formula can I use in the column 'E' to obtain the total number of leave days that would fall within the start and end dates of a task corresponding to a particular resource?

Notes:

- Working days are from Monday - Friday (leave impact from only
  weekdays should be considered)
- Holidays should not be considered in
  the calculation.
- Total leave will be inclusive of start and end
  dates.

I'd appreciate greatly any help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this only include working days? What days are counted as working days? Also, are holidays excluded? If so, what are the relevant holidays? (Bear in mind these can be country dependant.)

Comment: This would include only working days (Monday to Friday). I will not be including holidays in this sheet. Thanks!

Comment: Working days being Monday to Friday?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Resource 1 has  duplicated leave. Also, is leave inclusive of end date?

Comment: Leave is inclusive of the start and end dates. The leave end date for resource 1 (in column J1) should be 11/24/17.

Comment: Put all this additional info into the question. It will make it easier for people to help answer your question.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a short and snappy answer to overlapping date ranges. This is a similar sort of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258690/sum-the-number-of-days-in-one-date-range-which-fall-within-a-second-date-range/43260194#43260194

Comment: Also just to clarify, is it possible for the leave dates to be overlapping? Suppose resource 1 had dates of 11/3/17-11/5/17 and 11/4/17-11/6/17, would that be 6 days in total or 4 days (because it spans 11/3/17-11/6/17) ?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for late posting but this has taken a bit of thought. One way to do it is to generate an array of all the days in November, then test the array elements one at a time against each pair of leave dates to see if they fall within those dates, using countifs. So the basic formula is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$7,$A2,$I$2:$I$7,"<="&ROW(INDIRECT($C2&":"&$D2)),$J$2:$J$7,">="&ROW(INDIRECT($C2&":"&$D2))))
```

However we want to ignore weekends, so to do this I set all weekend dates to zero before counting up the matches

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$7,$A2,$I$2:$I$7,"<="&ROW(INDIRECT($C2&":"&$D2))*(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT($C2&":"&$D2)),2)<=5),$J$2:$J$7,">="&ROW(INDIRECT($C2&":"&$D2))))
```

A fairly long formula but it seems to give the correct results.

[image]

Columns E, L and M are for checking only and are not part of the final result in column F.

Comment: This works great! just a quick follow up; if i were to exclude the leave end date from the calculation how can I do this?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you would like to happen if the end date is excluded plz?

Comment: In fact use @Barry's answer! You can't add a condition to the range part of a countifs, so to do it with my answer you'd have to add an extra column to the leave dates with today's date in it where the end dates were blank.

Answer (score 1):

I used this "array formula" in `E2` confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down

`=SUM((H$2:H$7=A2)*TEXT(NETWORKDAYS(IF(I$2:I$7>C2,I$2:I$7,C2),IF(J$2:J$7<D2,J$2:J$7,D2)),"0;\0"))`

This checks that the Resource matches, and for all matching rows does a `NETWORKDAYS` calculation (which ignores weekends) within any overlapping date periods between leaves and tasks.

Where there is no overlap a negative value is returned so `TEXT` function is used to convert the negatives to zeroes.

`SUM` function sums the resulting array to give you the required total - see screenshot

If you want to allow blanks in the "leaves" end date field then you can use this adjusted version which will assume end date is today

`=SUM((H$2:H$7=A2)*TEXT(NETWORKDAYS(IF(I$2:I$7>C2,I$2:I$7,C2),IF(IF(J$2:J$7="",TODAY(),J$2:J$7)<D2,IF(J$2:J$7="",TODAY(),J$2:J$7),D2)),"0;\0"))`

...or you can replace the two instances of `TODAY()` with another date or cell reference containing a date

[image]

Comment: @Aquadjd - I updated my answer to cater for blanks in column J