# Getting average of top 1/3, second 1/3, and last 1/3 of values in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with numbers and a reference column. I'm trying to separate the numbers column into first third, second third, and last third and take the average of each.

```
Values  Ref column
 1.7     cow
 2.3     cow
 2.6     cow
 1.8     sheep
 1.3     sheep
 2.2     sheep
 1.5     sheep
 1.2     sheep
 2.3     sheep
 1.5     goose
 2.5     goose
```

So, for example, the average of the first two values for "sheep", second two, and last two. In other words, I want to take the average of each 1/3 of cells adjacent to "sheep".

Comment: By *"top third"* do you mean those values nearest to the top of the worksheet or those values largest in value ??

Comment: Do you want the average in the order they appear or ascending order of value? e.g. for sheep, are the two numbers you want to average 1.8 & 1.3 or 2.2 & 2.3? Where do you want the averages to appear? In another column against each row? Or do you enter 'sheep' and the 1st 1/3 2nd 1/3rd etc. appear in 3 cells? what if there aren't 3 even thirds? e.g. for goose? or there were 7 sheep values?

Comment: I tried this : AVERAGEIF(D6:D16,"sheep",C6:C16), which gives the average for all sheep, but I know it's not what you asked...

Comment: I'm looking for the physical top 1/3, not the largest 1/3 of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to cumulatively count the instances of the word you're looking at, then check that row number in your `AVERAGE`.

1. C2 = `=CountIf($B$2:$B2, $B2)` and fill down => values should be `{1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2}`
2. E1 = `sheep`
3. E2 = `=CountIf($B:$B, $E$1)` => `6`
4. E3 = `{=Average(If(($B:$B = $E$1) * ($C:$C <= $E$2 / 3), $A:$A))}` (note this is an array formula, as designated by the `{}` around it) => `1.55`
5. E3 = `{=Average(If(($B:$B = $E$1) * ($C:$C > $E$2 / 3) * ($C:$C <= 2 * $E$2 / 3), $A:$A))}` => `1.85`
6. E3 = `{=Average(If(($B:$B = $E$1) * ($C:$C > 2 * $E$2 / 3), $A:$A))}` => `1.75`

Array formulas, if I remember correctly, are entered the same as normal formulas (don't include the `{}`, that gets entered automatically), but you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (and possibly <kbd>Shift</kbd>) with <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you finish.

NB - these look at the entire column. You can speed them up by changing `$A:$A` to `$A$2:$A$12` (likewise for `$B:$B` and `$C:$C`). Just bear in mind that for any data you *append* to this list, you'll need to update the formulas; but you can *insert* data into the middle of the list and it will update them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

use a formula like this:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($D$2,B:B,0)+(D3-1)*COUNTIF(B:B,$D$2)/3):INDEX(A:A,MATCH($D$2,B:B,0)+((D3)*COUNTIF(B:B,$D$2)/3)-1))
```

This does require that the ref column be sorted and like references grouped.

[image]

[image]

---

This array formula will return the averages even if not sorted:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF($B$1:$B$12=$D$2,ROW($A$1:$A$12)*{1,1}))))),N(IF({1},ROW(INDEX(A:A,1+(D3-1)*COUNTIF(B:B,$D$2)/3):INDEX(A:A,D3*COUNTIF(B:B,$D$2)/3))))))
```

array formula need to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well supposing there *were* 7 sheep values and you wanted to do a weighted mean (e.g. the first mean would be calculated from the first two sheep plus a third of the third one)?

I have attempted a general solution for this dividing any number of animals into any number of fractions and finding their average values. My approach is to use the elegant overlap formula from @Barry Houdini as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507712/finding-and-adding-together-overlaps-in-dates-from-2-different-columns-in-excel/47519161#47519161) and work out the overlap between the intervals (in the case of 7 animals divided into 3):

```
0 to 2.33

2.33 to 4.67

4.67 to 7
```

and the numbers of the animals

```
0 to 1

1 to 2

2 to 3
```

and so on.

In H4

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)<=$H$2,ROWS($1:1)/$H$2*COUNTIF(B$2:B$16,$G$2),"")
```

In G4

```
=IF(H4="","",H4-COUNTIF(B$2:B$16,$G$2)/$H$2)
```

The main formula in I4 is

```
=IF(H4="","",SUM(TEXT(IF(C$2:C$16<H4,C$2:C$16,H4)-IF((C$2:C$16-1)>G4,C$2:C$16-1,G4),"general;\0")
*A$2:A$16*(B$2:B$16=$G$2))/(COUNTIF(B$2:B$16,$G$2)/$H$2))
```

entered as an array formula.

[image]

The fractions can be changed to halves, quarters etc. by changing the number in H2.