# Google Sheets: Repeat referencing in Formulas

Tags: google-sheets

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:B6<0,0,A1:B6))
```

The range is referred twice. Is it possible to do this with a singular reference within a formula?

Perhaps something akin to IFERROR like IFCONDITION(range, condition, result_if_condition)

The use case is the range itself are in many cases computed using complex arrangements - so it becomes quite inconvenient/unwieldy when that same complex arrangement needs to be inserted into multiple places.

Sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scZ_jlw6Wx1xH3gQ_z9rBAadyw6WxqcbFk10VQIDjHk/edit#gid=1028454630).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use

```
=ArrayFormula(text(A1:A6,"0;\0"))
```

so that any negative numbers are displayed as zero.

Since the result is a string, it may need to be coerced to a number for use in further calculations.

This was first suggested to me by @barry houdini - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507712/finding-and-adding-together-overlaps-in-dates-from-2-different-columns-in-excel/47519161#47519161) is an example of it in use (in Excel).

EDIT by OP (as in comment below) ;

Here is the link https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470 So if you wanted blank cells to be zero, you would set the 4th part to \0 i.e. =ArrayFormula(text(A1:A7,"0;\0;\0;\0")) because a blank cell is not a number.

Comment: Possible to get the link to the formatting options using TEXT? The Google help https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139 page does not show this option.

Comment: Specifically, is there also an option that can replace blank cells with zero ?

Comment: Here is the link https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en  So if you wanted blank cells to be zero, you would set the 4th part to \0 i.e. =ArrayFormula(text(A1:A7,"0;\0;\0;\0")) because a blank cell is not a number