# SUMIFS evaluating BEGIN and END Dates against another date period in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The datasets are as below:

**Salary Summary Table (A)**

[image]

**Source Salary Table (B)**

[image]

I have done the logic in SQL server but I am not having any luck converting it into Excel.

The logic to be converted from SQL into Excel is

A.SALARY is the SUM of rows in Table B when

1. A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
2. A.EMPL_RCD = B.EMPL_RCD
3. B.SLICE_BEGIN between A.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE **OR** B.SLICE_END between A.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE

I have done my own attempt of SUMIFS but it doesn't cater for the "OR" condition outlined in (3) above.

[image]

Just wondering what's the solution here and if someone could point me in the right direction.

Data:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+
| EMPLID  | EMPL_RCD | SLICE_BEGIN | SLICE_END  |  SALARY  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+
| 1000280 |        0 | 28/12/2017  | 10/01/2018 | 2,634.03 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 11/01/2018  | 24/01/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 25/01/2018  | 07/02/2018 | 2,634.05 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 08/02/2018  | 21/02/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 22/02/2018  | 07/03/2018 | 2,634.03 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 08/03/2018  | 21/03/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 22/03/2018  | 04/04/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 05/04/2018  | 18/04/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 19/04/2018  | 02/05/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 03/05/2018  | 16/05/2018 | 2,634.03 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 17/05/2018  | 30/05/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 31/05/2018  | 13/06/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 14/06/2018  | 27/06/2018 | 2,634.02 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 02/07/2018  | 11/07/2018 | 2,590.56 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 12/07/2018  | 25/07/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 26/07/2018  | 08/08/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 09/08/2018  | 22/08/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 23/08/2018  | 05/09/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 06/09/2018  | 19/09/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 20/09/2018  | 03/10/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 04/10/2018  | 17/10/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 18/10/2018  | 31/10/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 01/11/2018  | 14/11/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 15/11/2018  | 28/11/2018 | 2,631.30 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 01/12/2018  | 12/12/2018 | 2,675.62 |
| 1000280 |        0 | 13/12/2018  | 26/12/2018 | 2,686.70 |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Does it mean sum of salary between two date? Can you explain in simple sentence without SQL logic?

Comment: I have added your data in - please check is accurate. In future, this is how you should add data so people can test. I used https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables for formatting.

Comment: How are people supposed to calculate when a start date is between brackets e.g. your first start date? Are they to pro-rata equally across days ? To account for non-working days?

Comment: That would be a more challenging question, but I seem to remember @BarryHoudini coming up with an elegant answer using NetworkDays in an array formula.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507712/finding-and-adding-together-overlaps-in-dates-from-2-different-columns-in-excel/47522569 was the more general answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 3 SUMIFS like this:

```
=SUMIFS(L$5:L$30,H$5:H$30,A5,I$5:I$30,B5,J$5:J$30,">="&C5,J$5:J$30,"<="&D5)+
SUMIFS(L$5:L$30,H$5:H$30,A5,I$5:I$30,B5,K$5:K$30,">="&C5,K$5:K$30,"<="&D5)-
SUMIFS(L$5:L$30,H$5:H$30,A5,I$5:I$30,B5,J$5:J$30,">="&C5,J$5:J$30,"<="&D5,K$5:K$30,">="&C5,K$5:K$30,"<="&D5)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly. Very nice. I used the same logic, only within `SUMPRODUCT`. It ends up being just a bit shorter, but harder to follow.

Comment: Just curious, but when reproducing the data into a manageable format (which the OP failed to do), did you pick up on the 14 day interval pattern and how long did it take you to locate the non-series dates in J18:J19 and J30:J31?

Comment: It was mostly the work of @Qharr, but the answer is no, I was oblivious to it TBH.

Answer (score 3):

For a more complex take on this, done for personal enjoyment. Simplest is best, however; [@Tom Sharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894917/tom-sharpe)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53811593/9245853) is much more intuitive.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT($L$5:$L$30*($H$5:$H$30=A5)*($I$5:$I$30=B5)*
 ABS((($J$5:$J$30>=C5)*($J$5:$J$30<=D5))+(($K$5:$K$30>=C5)*($K$5:$K$30<=D5))
 *(($J$5:$J$30>=C5)*($J$5:$J$30<=D5))-(($K$5:$K$30>=C5)*($K$5:$K$30<=D5))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim DateStart As Date, DateFinish As Date
    Dim Total As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 3 To 5

                DateStart = .Range("C" & j).Value - 1
                DateFinish = .Range("D" & j).Value + 1
                Total = 0

                For i = 5 To LastRow
                    If j = 3 And i = 5 Then
                        If .Range("J" & i).Value < DateStart And .Range("K" & i).Value < DateFinish Then
                            Total = Total + .Range("L" & i).Value
                        End If
                    Else
                        If .Range("J" & i).Value > DateStart And .Range("K" & i).Value < DateFinish Then
                            Total = Total + .Range("L" & i).Value
                        End If
                    End If

                Next i

                Range("E" & j).Value = Total

            Next j
    End With

 End Sub
```