# Sum hours worked between multiple time frames based on punch times and criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stumped and need some help from you guys.

I have a list of Punch Times (Sheet2) with their respective Departments:

[image: Data_Format]

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the data summed/consolidated into this format (Sheet1):

[image: Final_Format]

The solution for C5 would sum the total number of hours worked between 12 AM and 1 AM (using Punch Times on Sheet2 Col G & I) on Sundays (Sheet2 Col K) for Department 300 (Sheet2 Column R) stated in Sheet1 B2.

Note: Punch Out Time cannot go past 12 AM. If they work past 12 AM a new record will start underneath with 12 AM as the Punch In Time.

I can write a formula to grab the total time for each individual record and time frame, but I don't want to add a bunch of columns to the dataset and rather sum all the records in one cell (Sheet1 C5).

Is there any way to do this with a single formula?

Thanks!

Comment: SUMIFS most likely will do what you want.

Comment: Can you please clarify further? What would my sum range be in this case?

Comment: Agreed, SUMIFS is the easiest formula-based solution, however I recommend going with a Pivot Table instead

Comment: Can you help direct me to a Pivot based solution? I don't see how I can take Punch Times and convert them to hours worked for specific times of the day.

Comment: It's unclear how you want to read each record. Say for example your first record in your table, where you have 8 hours worked on saturday starting at 7 am. Do you want to return an 8 in cell `I12` or do you want to spread those 8 hours worked on the range `I12:I19`? If it's the latter it becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: I'd like to spread the 8 hours down the column I12:I19.

Comment: Then neither SUMIFS nor a Pivot will help you and it's a much more complicated problem, I recommend looking for a VBA solution

Comment: It looks like a fairly standard overlap example - refer to @Barry Houdini https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507712/finding-and-adding-together-overlaps-in-dates-from-2-different-columns-in-excel/47519161#47519161 before jumping into VBA too quickly (the example is with dates but the logic is the same)

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of that. The logic is a little different because of the fractions, but that should solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the overlap formula for two date ranges adapted for the current scenario using time differences:

```
=SUM((Sheet1!$R$2:$R$4=$B$2)*(Sheet1!$L$2:$L$4=C$4)*TEXT((IF(Sheet1!$J$2:$J$4<$B5,Sheet1!$J$2:$J$4,$B5)-IF(Sheet1!$H$2:$H$4>$A5,Sheet1!$H$2:$H$4,$A5))*24,"general;\0"))
```

Must be entered as an array formula (pre-O365) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Sheet1 contains

[image]

and Sheet2 contains

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tom Sharpe, I was struggling with the replace of NETWORKDAYS from your post mentioned above. It works great, although it seems to be taking any records with a 12AM punch out time and not counting them properly. If a punch time passes midnight, the record will punch out at 12 AM and start a new record with 12AM as punch in time to continue the shift. I'm struggling to find a way to adjust to accommodate the missing records. Thanks for your time

Comment: Fixed by changing all the punch out times to 1 instead of 0. Thanks!

Comment: I see what you mean - midnight would be treated as 0 I think so wouldn't work properly for (say) a 10pm-5am shift. Glad you managed to fix it and it worked for you in the end.